# Using IN in MYSQL cause issues with variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When working on a site, I found a fairly weird issue with PDO. The following code only selects posts made by user 1, not or 3.

```
$sql = "SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE userid IN (:friends)";
$pdo->prepare($sql);
$pdo->execute(array(':friends' => '1, 2, 3'));
```

However the following code selects post from all three:

```
$sql = "SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE userid IN (1, 2, 3)";
$pdo->prepare($sql);
$pdo->execute();
```

Why is this, and what can I do to make the first work like the second?

Comment: Something is missing - `selects posts made by user 1, not or 3`. Do you mean `1, not 2 or 3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO prepared statement IN() array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763224/php-pdo-prepared-statement-in-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO binding values for MySQL IN statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586587/pdo-binding-values-for-mysql-in-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You must write query like this

```
$sql = "SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE userid IN (:friend1, :friend2, :friend3)";
$pdo->prepare($sql);
$pdo->execute([
    ':friend1' => '1',
    ':friend2' => '2',
    ':friend3' => '3',
]);
```