# How to query a database with an array in the where clause in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Hi guys I am trying to select all the users in my database with an array of USER ID. I am coding in PHP and this is my code so far but I get an error saying I am trying to use an array.

```
$relative = $this->db->select('user_id, fname, surname')->get_where('user_view_view', array('user_id'=>$mytest))->result_array();
```

My array of user ids is called:

```
$mytest
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Using PDO with IN clause array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)

Answer (score 1):

try something like that

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('user_id, fname, surname')
    ->from("user_view_view")
    ->where_in("user_id",$myTest)
    ->get();

$relative = $query->result_array();
```

the reason why it won't work is because get_where doesn't accept an array as field_value

you should get an error with the message "Array to string conversion"

Comment: my page just loads blank meaning there is an error in the code.

Comment: set the environment to development - i'm really unable to help without the error message