# PHP, PDO bindValue - how to pass comma seperated INTs for use with 'in clause'

Tags: php, mysql, data-binding, pdo

I'm trying to get a MySQL query similar to this one to work using PHP and PDO

```
select user_id from  users where user_id in (7,8,9)
```

If I do this:

```
$userlist ='7,8,9';
$stmt->bindValue(':userlist', $userlist, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The MySQL server log records:

```
2016-01-27T16:51:52.644453Z   32 Prepare    select user_id from  users where user_id in (?)
2016-01-27T16:51:52.644489Z   32 Execute    select user_id from  users where user_id in ('7,8,9')
```

And only the row where user_id is 7 is returned.

If I do this:

```
$userlist ='7,8,9';
$stmt->bindValue(':userlist', (int)$userlist, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

MySQL logs this:

```
2016-01-27T16:54:09.110990Z   33 Prepare    select user_id from  users where user_id in (?)
2016-01-27T16:54:09.111026Z   33 Execute    select user_id from  users where user_id in (7)
```

And again I only see one of three rows. I feel this must have a very basic solution, but I've not been able to find it..

Comment: You need to make as many parameters in your IN clausel as many ids you want to return.

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois - thanks, just seen this. re your comment in the answer below,  I feel it would be nice to have something like PDO::PARAM_array for this common case

Comment: You may take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array).

Answer (score -1):

You must bind each value

```
select user_id from  users where user_id in (:id1,:id2,:id3)
```

For this query:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':id1', 7);
$stmt->bindValue(':id2', 8);
$stmt->bindValue(':id3', 9);
```

Or you may use some query builder. For example, what you may do with [Yii2's query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html):

```
// ...WHERE (`status` = 10) AND (`type` IS NULL) AND (`id` IN (4, 8, 15))
$query->where([
    'status' => 10,
    'type' => null,
    'id' => [4, 8, 15],
]);
```

Comment: Really?????? (my incredulity is not aimed at you, but the fact that this is the solution). This seems to be an incredible amount of work for what must be a very common requirement.

Comment: Yes, it is not very handy, but you may use one of query builders, what solves this and similar tasks

Comment: @KevInSol One paramater equals to one binding value. You cannot just tell the database server you have one parameter and send 3 values and expect the database server to know you meant this one parameter is for all 3 values.

Comment: Thank you, I saw your edit there. I'd rather not have to go learn something else or add in extra libraries etc. I'll have a go at my own function. Will post it here is I get something working.