# Create SQL from array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL Query that gets data from my DB depending on what the array includes.

Example:

My array includes `1, 2, 3` then the query should be `SELECT * FROM v WHERE category='1' OR category='2' OR category='3'`.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Any tips are welcome.

**UPDATE:**

Using MySQL as DB.

Comment: Please add which DB product you use (e.g. MySQL)

Comment: are you not getting desired result as per your given query ?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer The query should work. I just need some help creating the query from my array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `implode` function and `IN` clause as

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM v WHERE category IN ('".implode("','", $your_array)."')";
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767572/755949, which uses placeholders and PDO to add the parameters to your query. Going with Saty's answer you could risk ending up with a SQL injection.

Comment: I'm using PDO at my DB class. All data is sanitized

Comment: FYI I don't know how you santize the data. If you concat a SQL query, with unsantized data, and pass that query to PDO then PDO won't do any sanitizing for you.

Comment: The DB class sanitizes the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$where = 'WHERE category="' . implode('" OR category="', $array) . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM v WHERE ( FIND_IN_SET(".implode("','", $your_array).", category) ) ";
```

For more info about FIND_IN_SET: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php