# bind IN() and other variable in single query pdo

Tags: arrays, pdo, binding

I have used   [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array) to bind IN() condition , But still my issue is

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($in_array) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_value IN ($in) and other_value='$variable' ";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($in_array);
```

How to bind the **$variable** with in this query ?

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, build an array of placeholders, add an extra placeholder for your extra `$variable`, then add `$variable`'s value to the array you pass into the `execute()` call:

```
$temp = array_fill('?', count($array_in) - 1);
$placeholders = implode(',', $temp);

$array_in[] = $variable; // add your $variable to the values list

$sql = "SELECT ... IN ($placeholders) AND other_value = ?"; // insert placeholders string into query
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array_in);
```

Comment: can you tell how to insert the placeholders string in to query ?

Comment: ewps. used the wrong var. should've been `$placeholders` in the `$sql` line.

Comment: finally fixed...your help is appreciated