# Mysql data table in PHP where user can select multiple options for filtering

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table displayed on a webpage using the following php code.  I also have a dropdown menu above the mysql table that will allow you to select which team you want to view and filter out any other teams.

The problem I am having though, I used bootstrap and jquery to make the dropdown menu able to select multiple teams, but my php code will still only take 1 Team after you submit multiple selected teams.  Any ideas?  Thank you for any help you may provide.

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wordpress_10';
$username = 'zzz';
$password = 'yyy';

try{

    $con = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (Exception $ex) {

    echo 'Not Connected '.$ex->getMessage();
}

$tableContent = '';
$start = '';
$selectStmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM WR_TeamAnalyzer');
$selectStmt->execute();
$rows = $selectStmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $tableContent = $tableContent.'<tr>'.
             '<td>' . $row['WR'] .'</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['Team'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['WK'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['Opp'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['T'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['Yds'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['TDs'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['Fpts'] . '</td>';
}

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$start = $_POST['start'];
$tableContent = '';
$selectStmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM WR_TeamAnalyzer WHERE TEAM like :start');
$selectStmt->execute(array(

         ':start'=>$start.'%'

));
$rows = $selectStmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $tableContent = $tableContent.'<tr>'.
             '<td>' . $row['WR'] .'</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['Team'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['WK'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['Opp'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['T'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['Yds'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['TDs'] . '</td>'
            .'<td>' . $row['Fpts'] . '</td>';
}

}

?>

         <script type="text/javascript">
                                    jQuery(function($) {
                                        $('#teammultiselect').multiselect();
                                    });
                                </script>
        <form action="<?php get_permalink('1839'); ?>" method="POST">

            <select id="teammultiselect" name="start" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="">Team</option>
                        <option value="ARI" <?php if($start == 'ARI'){echo 'selected';}?>>ARI</option>
                        <option value="ATL" <?php if($start == 'ATL'){echo 'selected';}?>>ATL</option>
                        <option value="BAL" <?php if($start == 'BAL'){echo 'selected';}?>>BAL</option>
                        <option value="BUF" <?php if($start == 'BUF'){echo 'selected';}?>>BUF</option>
                        <option value="CAR" <?php if($start == 'CAR'){echo 'selected';}?>>CAR</option>
                        <option value="CHI" <?php if($start == 'CHI'){echo 'selected';}?>>CHI</option>
                        <option value="CIN" <?php if($start == 'CIN'){echo 'selected';}?>>CIN</option>
                        <option value="CLE" <?php if($start == 'CLE'){echo 'selected';}?>>CLE</option>
                        <option value="DAL" <?php if($start == 'DAL'){echo 'selected';}?>>DAL</option>
                        <option value="DEN" <?php if($start == 'DEN'){echo 'selected';}?>>DEN</option>
                        <option value="DET" <?php if($start == 'DET'){echo 'selected';}?>>DET</option>
                        <option value="GB" <?php if($start == 'GB'){echo 'selected';}?>>GB</option>
                        <option value="HOU" <?php if($start == 'HOU'){echo 'selected';}?>>HOU</option>
                        <option value="IND" <?php if($start == 'IND'){echo 'selected';}?>>IND</option>
                        <option value="JAX" <?php if($start == 'JAX'){echo 'selected';}?>>JAX</option>
                        <option value="KC" <?php if($start == 'KC'){echo 'selected';}?>>KC</option>
                        <option value="LA" <?php if($start == 'LA'){echo 'selected';}?>>LA</option>
                        <option value="MIA" <?php if($start == 'MIA'){echo 'selected';}?>>MIA</option>
                        <option value="MIN" <?php if($start == 'MIN'){echo 'selected';}?>>MIN</option>
                        <option value="NE" <?php if($start == 'NE'){echo 'selected';}?>>NE</option>
                        <option value="NO" <?php if($start == 'NO'){echo 'selected';}?>>NO</option>
                        <option value="NYG" <?php if($start == 'NYG'){echo 'selected';}?>>NYG</option>
                        <option value="NYJ" <?php if($start == 'NYJ'){echo 'selected';}?>>NYJ</option>
                        <option value="OAK" <?php if($start == 'OAK'){echo 'selected';}?>>OAK</option>
                        <option value="PHI" <?php if($start == 'PHI'){echo 'selected';}?>>PHI</option>
                        <option value="PIT" <?php if($start == 'PIT'){echo 'selected';}?>>PIT</option>
                        <option value="SD" <?php if($start == 'SD'){echo 'selected';}?>>SD</option>
                        <option value="SEA" <?php if($start == 'SEA'){echo 'selected';}?>>SEA</option>
                        <option value="SF" <?php if($start == 'SF'){echo 'selected';}?>>SF</option>
                        <option value="TB" <?php if($start == 'TB'){echo 'selected';}?>>TB</option>
                        <option value="TEN" <?php if($start == 'TEN'){echo 'selected';}?>>TEN</option>
                        <option value="WAS" <?php if($start == 'WAS'){echo 'selected';}?>>WAS</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find">

            <table id='trend' class='wpDataTable dataTable'><tr><th>WR</th><th>Tm</th><th>Wk</th><th>Opp</th><th>T</th><th>Yds</th><th>TDs</th><th>Fpts</th></tr>

                <?php

                echo $tableContent;

                ?>

            </table>

        </form>
```

Comment: You really do need to learn more about loops because there's ridiculous amounts of repetition in this code.

Comment: Use the `in()` operator instead of a `like`

Comment: Thank you for the tip gapman, is there anyone that could offer assistance?

Comment: I will give that a try, thank you shadow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Using PDO with IN clause array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)

Comment: Btw, you do not need to use prepared statement for your 1st query,  it is just a waste of resources.