# PDO Bind IN with WHERE AND

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-injection

[PHP - Using PDO with IN clause array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)
I have seen these but it only says to BIND IN but i also want other parameters with IN.

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN($list_of_ids) AND type = $type AND something != $something "
```

How can i do this with PDO ?

Comment: [Prepared statements and IN clause](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in)

Comment: ok array merge i got it thanks to YOUR COMMON SEXSE