# Dynamic amount of SQL where statements in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have an array with a dynamic amount of strings

```
$arr = array("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc");
```

How would I create an SQL statement such as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=? OR name=? OR name=?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $arr));
```

Dynamically

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767651/3585500) (and the [one below it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767572/3585500) )  on how to build a PDO prepared statement with a dynamic number of values. As in... `WHERE name in (?, ?, ?, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the CI Query Builder you can use `where_in` (also `or_where_in`) functions.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

> $this->db->where_in()
>
> Generates a WHERE field IN (‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query joined with AND if appropriate
>
> $names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
>
> $this->db->where_in('username', $names);
>
> // Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')

```
 $arr = array('a','b','c');
 $this->db->where_in('name', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you are looking for. It will dynamically create an sql query based on how big your array is.

```
$arr = array("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE";
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i ++){
   if($i > 0){
        $sql .= " OR "; 
   }
   $sql .= " name=?";
}
echo $sql; // SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=? OR name=? OR name=?
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)?

```
$arr = array("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
$sql .= implode(' OR ', array_fill(0, count($arr), 'name=?'));
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $arr));
```