# Can PDO bindParam() or bindValue() make the db does soft parsing?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb, bindparam

With `PHP`, I am trying to execute many queries with PDO in for loop and I want to make the `DB` optimizer does the soft parsing.

I am binding parameters now but I am not sure if the optimizer really uses the soft parsing.

**The sample query**

```
select * from table as t where t.id = :id ;
```

**`PHP` code**

```
$query = "select * from table as t where t.id = :id ;"
$pdo->prepare($query);
$id = 0;
$query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
for($id; $id<10; $id++){
    $query->execute()
}
```

Comment: Please define "soft parsing".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what a soft parsing is but a query in your case gets parsed only once which is probably what you are asking about.

A couple notes.

1. You need to make sure that the [emulation mode is turned off](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation).
2. With such a simple query you won't likely notice any performance improvement. Parsing is *really* fast nowadays.
3. Although I understand that your query is just an example, nevertheless, instead of running a SELECT a query in a loop it will be better [gather all ids into `IN()` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767651/285587) in a single query or use a JOIN if applicable.
4. running multiple similar queries is rather justified with DML statements. In such a case, if your concern is performance, I would rather advise to wrap all queries in a transaction, it could greatly improve the speed in some circumstances

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
My query is actually very long and I joined many tables on it.. and my customers search many kinds of information on my website using the query. so I was curious.

Comment: @체라치에 but you don't run a search query in a loop so I am at loss what is your question really about

Comment: They send me many similar queries like this (this one is very simplified for an example)

    "select * from table_a a, table_b b where a.id = 2 and b.dt >= '2019-10-01' and b.dt <= '2019-10-10' and a.id = b.id;"

so I was curious if I write the query and bind parameters from customers' input then execute in PHP PDO like this

    "select * from table_a a, table_b b where a.id = :id and b.dt >= :start_dt and b.dt <= :end_dt and a.id = b.id;"

so my question is.. In this way, will the optimizer use query_cache? or just hard parse it again and again..

Comment: This is **entirely** different question.

Comment: that's why I mentioned soft parse.. okay I will open another question.

Comment: The Query Cache is _not_ involved.  It comes into play only when the _identical_ query is posted twice without any changes to the table meanwhile.

Comment: Binding is a very small part of the execution time.