# why wont this query delete details from all tables?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to delete records from tables matching users ID while i delete the user. but somehow it deletes records only from the cv table.

what i am trying is

```
if($_GET['deluser'] !='1'){

         $qr = "delete from members where member_id IN(".$_GET['deluser'].")";
         $qr = "delete from company where caller_id IN(".$_GET['deluser'].")";
         $qr = "delete from cv where agent_id IN(".$_GET['deluser'].")";
         $st = $db->prepare($qr);
         $st->execute();        

    header('Location: users.php?action=DELETED');
    exit;
```

what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Because you execute only one query. All above are overwritten without execution.

Comment: How can i delete all at once?

Comment: assign-prepare-execute-assign next- prepare next-...

Comment: Thanks Akina for the help.

Comment: There's no point in using prepare() if you don't use prepared statements.

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi can you show me some examples?

Comment: @RogerRhode Check the official PHP documentation regarding that topic. It also helps you secure your query against SQL injections. If you paste the value from your GET parameter "deluser" without validation into your query string it's highly insecure and should not be used for production code.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case you overwrite the value in `$qr` every time so you need to execute it, everyone of them separately,

you need also to fix the `SQL` injection problem so you can fix it 
by using bind your data in the `execute` method or by using `bindParam`

first, you need to add `?` with the same number of input you want to pass

you can check how it work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array/14767651#14767651) in this answer

```
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count(explode(',', $_GET['deluser'])) - 1) . '?';
```

```
$qr = "delete from members where member_id IN($in)";
$st = $db->prepare($qr);
$st->execute(explode(',', $_GET['deluser']));   

$qr = "delete from company where caller_id IN($in)";
$st = $db->prepare($qr);
$st->execute(explode(',', $_GET['deluser']));   

$qr = "delete from cv where agent_id IN($in)";
$st = $db->prepare($qr);
$st->execute(explode(',', $_GET['deluser']));
```

You can read more about [BindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [Execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) in the docs

Comment: Thanks mate for your help.

Comment: Hi yes have heard and I understand i need to Bind the variables instead of using GET right?

Comment: Once you fix the SQL injection, ping me and I will remove downvote.

Comment: @Dharman check the answer again i update it

Comment: it won't do. you need  a separate placeholder for the every user id

Comment: but how can this be fixed he didn't mention how many `userid` he want to add

Comment: @YourCommonSense if you could fix it please edit it

Comment: [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767651/285587)

Comment: Here's a lesson for you for the future: don't answer badly written questions with missing details. Now you are in a pickle, because the proper solution is not so easy and the solution the OP accepted is extremely bad. This answer can still be saved and improved.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  i read it it's really awesome answer thanks for booth of you, please check my answer again i think it is correct now

Comment: @Dharman is it correct now ?

Comment: Not yet. `$_GET['deluser']` is a string. I assume you need to explode it into an array first.

Comment: You can't say that it is a string without the form, but in general because he use  `in` operator in his mysql query so he sure from that before

Comment: All get parameters are a string. I think it is something like this: `1,2,3,4`, so they would need to split it up into an array.

Comment: @Dharman i think that the answer now is completely complete

Comment: Yes, it's quite good. Surprisingly you already have 5 upvotes on it. I think you now see the benefit in improving the answer.

Comment: @Dharman really i learn a lot from you about improve the answer thanks a lot :)