# How can I answer with array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

i can explain with an example

```
$sorgu=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=:name1 OR name=:name2");
$sorgu->execute(['name1' => "John",'name2' => "Aydin"]);
$cikti=$sorgu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

i can get what i want this way but should there be a more practical way?
is there like this one way?

```
$answers=['John','Aydin'];
$sorgu=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=:names");
$sorgu->execute(['names' => $answers]);
$cikti=$sorgu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

i think this isn't work but i want to know there's should better way?

Comment: [PHP - Using PDO with IN clause array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)

Comment: Thank You that's what i looking for

Comment: i am sorry, i need help. `(products_category IN (:category))`  it's not working only on category,
if :category is 1 not problem but 1,22,23 it's not working

Comment: It's explained in the second link.

Comment: yep it's true i am sorry