# MySQL: DELETE NOT IN with a POST value and PDO Prepare deletes all records

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post, pdo

I have a simple table containing user_id and user_hash.

All of the hashes need to be deleted except some ones, via an AJAX call. The hashes that need to be kept are sent thru a POST variable.

**HTML code**

```
<button data-hash="'M3FYck9KemhVSk5iYW9YcFpSTExMQT09', 'eTlSQ0NMSW1PT2NLOTNaUHlPWEtKQT09'" class="purge">Purge</button>
```

**JQuery code**

```
$('.purge').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   hash = $(this).attr('data-hash');
   $.ajax({
      url: "includes/db.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { type: 'purge', hash: hash },
      success: function () {
      }
   });
});
```

**PHP code of db.php**

```
elseif ($_POST["type"] == 'purge') {
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM users_hash WHERE hash NOT IN (:hash)");
   $arr_update = array('hash' => $_POST["hash"]);
   $stmt->execute($arr_update);
}
```

But this delete **all** the records of users_hash!

However, if I add this code in the db.php file

```
echo "DELETE FROM users_hash WHERE hash NOT IN (".$_POST["hash"].")";
```

This is displayed in the Chrome Devtools

```
DELETE 
FROM users_hash 
WHERE hash NOT IN ('M3FYck9KemhVSk5iYW9YcFpSTExMQT09',
                   'eTlSQ0NMSW1PT2NLOTNaUHlPWEtKQT09')
```

which works as expected.

Preparing the query with PDO changes something, but I dont know what.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Using PDO with IN clause array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array)

Answer (score 1):

PDO sends your list as ONE literal, i.e. as

```sql
DELETE 
FROM users_hash 
WHERE hash NOT IN ('M3FYck9KemhVSk5iYW9YcFpSTExMQT09, eTlSQ0NMSW1PT2NLOTNaUHlPWEtKQT09')
```

Use NOT FIND_IN_SET:

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM users_hash WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(hash, :hash)");
```

Comment: Just to settle the recent discussion, I checked the explain. FIND_IN_SET(field, 'csv') didn't use an index. And a quick google-ing finds that [it is not only me](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37564). Hence your solution, albeit a sleek one, cannot be recommended as a generic approach.