# SQLSRV using an array for the IN clause in the UPDATE statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to update a table where column `user_id` has values, stored in an array, but I get this error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207
> [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Invalid column name 'Array'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Array'. ) )

This is my code:

```
$sql = "
   SELECT usuario_id 
   FROM control_asistencias 
   WHERE 
      ano=".$ano." and 
      mes=".$mes." and 
      dia".$dia."='T' and 
      comida_habitual ='T' 
";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

if( $stmt === false ) {
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}


$usuarios_comida_habitual = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    array_push($usuarios_comida_habitual,$row['usuario_id']);
}

// Una vez que tenemos los usuarios Que han fichado para ese dia hacemos un Update

$sql_update = "
   UPDATE VLD_PRESENCIA 
   SET VLD_PRESENCIA_DIA".$dia." = 'T' 
   WHERE 
      VLD_PRESENCIA_CODUSUARIO IN (".$usuarios_comida_habitual.") AND
      VLD_PRESENCIA_COMIDA_HABITUAL = 'T'
   ";
     
   $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn2, $sql_update);
   if( $stmt2 === false ) {
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
   }
   else
   {
      echo 'eureka';
   }
```

Is it possible that the way the array was passed is wrong? Or is it possible to put the condition that I want to implement what `userid` should be in that array?

I found this

```
 array_walk($usuarios_comida_habitual , 'intval');
 $ids = implode(',', $usuarios_comida_habitual);
```

i Do this before generating $sql_update

Comment: If you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Although using an array for the `IN` clause has already a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array), you may try to use the `sqlsrv_prepare()\sqlsrv_execute()` combination to prepare a statement and execute it multiple times. But in both cases you need to consider the following:

- Always try to use parameters in your statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues.
- When the column name is used dynamically (possible wrong design), check the genarated name using `sys.columns` system catalog view to prevent possible SQL injection issues.

Note, the reason for your error is the fact, that you are trying to build an SQL statement concatenating a string literal and a PHP array.

The following example, based on your code and using parameterized queries, is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?php
// SELECT statement
$sql = "
    SELECT usuario_id 
    FROM control_asistencias 
    WHERE ano = ? AND mes = ? AND dia".$dia." = 'T' AND comida_habitual = 'T' 
";
$params = array($ano, $mes);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if ( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
$usuarios_comida_habitual = array();
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $usuarios_comida_habitual[] = $row['usuario_id'];
}

// Multiple UPDATE statements
$sql = "
    UPDATE VLD_PRESENCIA 
    SET VLD_PRESENCIA_DIA".$dia." = 'T' 
    WHERE 
        VLD_PRESENCIA_CODUSUARIO = ? AND 
        VLD_PRESENCIA_COMIDA_HABITUAL = 'T'
";
$usuario = 0;
$params2 = array(&$usuario);
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_prepare($conn2, $sql, $params2);
if ( $stmt2 === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
foreach ($usuarios_comida_habitual as $usuario) {
    if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt2) === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    } else {
        echo 'eureka';
    }
}   
?>
```

If you want to execute a single `UPDATE` statement, the following approach is an option, but again with parameterized statement:

```
<?php
// SELECT statement
$sql = "
    SELECT usuario_id 
    FROM control_asistencias 
    WHERE ano = ? AND mes = ? AND dia".$dia." = 'T' AND comida_habitual = 'T' 
";
$params = array($ano, $mes);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if ( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
$usuarios_comida_habitual = array();
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $usuarios_comida_habitual[] = $row['usuario_id'];
}

// Single UPDATE statement
$usuarios_placeholders = substr(str_repeat(',?', count($usuarios_comida_habitual)), 1);
$sql = "
    UPDATE VLD_PRESENCIA 
    SET VLD_PRESENCIA_DIA".$dia." = 'T' 
    WHERE 
        VLD_PRESENCIA_CODUSUARIO IN (".$usuarios_placeholders.") AND 
        VLD_PRESENCIA_COMIDA_HABITUAL = 'T'
";
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn2, $sql, $usuarios_comida_habitual);
if ( $stmt2 === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
} else {
        echo 'eureka';
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a single SQL query without any loop since `IN` supports subqueries. And since connections run across different servers, consider `OPENROWSET` for [ad hoc queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/ad-hoc-distributed-queries-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15). Adjust ODBC connection string parameters and `[database].[schema]` identifiers accordingly. (Note: default schema is `dbo`).

```php
$sql = "UPDATE VLD_PRESENCIA 
        SET VLD_PRESENCIA_DIA".$dia." = 'T' 
        WHERE VLD_PRESENCIA_CODUSUARIO 
           IN (SELECT sub.usuario_id 
               FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
                               'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;UID=userID;PWD=password',
                               'SELECT * FROM [database].[schema].control_asistencias') sub
               WHERE sub.ano = ? 
                 AND sub.mes = ? 
                 AND sub.dia".$dia." = 'T'
                 AND sub.comida_habitual = 'T') 
        AND VLD_PRESENCIA_COMIDA_HABITUAL = 'T'"; 

$prms = array($ano, $mes);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $prms);

if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Seems reasonable, if `$conn` and `$conn2` hold a connection to the same server and database.

Comment: @Zhorov, good catch! I adjusted SQL assuming both connections are to same server, not necessarily same database.

Comment: This is a test, but connections are in different server

Comment: Then, consider [ad hoc queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/ad-hoc-distributed-queries-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) to query from different backends. Edit shows `OPENROWSET`.