# How to PDO query to retrieve rows that match a value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a table with column nearbyAttractions which contains values seperated by a comma. For example A001,A002

I am querying that column then converting the contents to an array called $NearbyAttractionsArray.

print_r($NearbyAttractionsArray);

Array ( [0] => A001 [1] => A003 )

I want to run a PDO SQL query to find records that match for each value of the array then output them in a loop.

$arrayQuery = $this->con->prepare("SELECT attid, attTitle, attThumbnail, AttTagline FROM attractions WHERE
attid=$NearbyAttractionsArray AND attStatus=1");

$arrayQuery->execute();

when I try this it converts $NearbyAttractionsArray to a string called array...

What would be the correct syntax to output values attid, attTitle, attThumbnail, AttTagline for each row where attId matches one of the values in the array?

I suspect some kind of foreach loop would be needed but cannot find the correct way to write this as a PDO statement.

Many thanks

For perspective my complete class code is:

```
<?php 

class NearbyAttractionsProvider {

private $con, $attId;

    public function __construct($con, $attId) {
        $this->con = $con;
        $this->attId = $attId;
    } // end of constructor


    public function createNearbyAttractionsList($con, $attId) {
        $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT nearbyAttractions FROM attractions WHERE attId=:attId");
            $query->bindParam(":attId", $attId);
            $query->execute();

            $this->sqlData = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $NearbyAttractions = $this->sqlData["nearbyAttractions"];
            $NearbyAttractionsRemoveCommas = str_replace(',', '',$NearbyAttractions);
            $NearbyAttractionsArray = str_split($NearbyAttractionsRemoveCommas, 4);

            print_r($NearbyAttractionsArray);

            $CountNearbyAttractions = sizeof($NearbyAttractionsArray);

            if($NearbyAttractionsArray[0] != "") {
                $results = "<h3>There are $CountNearbyAttractions Nearby Attractions</h3>";

                $arrayQuery = $this->con->prepare("SELECT attid, attTitle, attThumbnail, AttTagline FROM attractions WHERE 
                                attid=$NearbyAttractionsArray AND attStatus=1");
                $arrayQuery->execute();

                $results .= "<div class='nearbyAttractionsItemsContainer'>";
                while($row = $arrayQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $id = $row["attid"];
                        $img = $row["attThumbnail"];
                        $title = $row["attTitle"];
                        $tagline = $row["AttTagline"];

                $results .= "<div class='nearbyAttractionListItem'>
                                <a href='Attraction.php?attId=$id&title=$title' data-AttractionId='$id' 
                                class'NearbyAttractionItem-url'>
                                <img class='NearbyAttractionItem-thumbnail' src='$img' height='220' width=300'>
                                <h3 class='NearbyAttractionItem-title'>$title</h3>
                                <p class='NearbyAttractionItem-tagline'>$tagline</p>
                                </a>
                            </div>";
                } // End of while loop
            $results .= "</div>"; // End of nearbyAttractionsItemsContainer

            } // End of IF statement

            else {
                $results = "<h3>There are No Nearby Attractions</h3>";
            } // End of Else statement

        return $results;         

    } // End of public function createNearbyAttractionsList

} // End pf class NearbyAttractionsProvider
```

Comment: See this possible dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array

Comment: Why don't you simply do a join?

Comment: This is another good example of why comma delimited data is a bad choice for DB column. If this were just in a 1nf you could use a subquery. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: A join is to link rows in two or more tables but here there is only 1 table so not a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like:

```sql
SELECT attid, attTitle, attThumbnail, AttTagline 
FROM attractions 
WHERE attid IN('A001', 'A003')
AND attStatus=1
```

Of course I assume that `attid` stores atomic values. To convert array items to string you can use [foreach() loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or [implode() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). In second case, you'll need wrap it with apostrophes before you'll join it.

Comment: Placeholders should be joined, no need for apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Many hours of fannying around and it works with a foreach loop.

```
<?php 
    
    class NearbyAttractionsProvider {
    
    private $con, $attId;
    
        public function __construct($con, $attId) {
            $this->con = $con;
            $this->attId = $attId;
        } // end of constructor
    
    
        public function createNearbyAttractionsList($con, $attId) {
            $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT nearbyAttractions FROM attractions WHERE attId=:attId");
                $query->bindParam(":attId", $attId);
                $query->execute();
    
                $this->sqlData = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $NearbyAttractions = $this->sqlData["nearbyAttractions"];
                $NearbyAttractionsRemoveCommas = str_replace(',', '',$NearbyAttractions);
                $NearbyAttractionsArray = str_split($NearbyAttractionsRemoveCommas, 5);
    
                $CountNearbyAttractions = sizeof($NearbyAttractionsArray);
    
                if($NearbyAttractionsArray[0] != "") {
                    $results = "<h3>There are $CountNearbyAttractions Nearby Attractions</h3>";
    
                    foreach($NearbyAttractionsArray as $row) {
    
                        $arrayQuery = $this->con->prepare("SELECT attId, attTitle, attThumbnail, AttTagline FROM attractions WHERE 
                                    attId=:row AND attStatus=1");
                        $arrayQuery->bindParam(":row", $row);
                        $arrayQuery->execute();
    
                        $results .= "<div class='nearbyAttractionsItemsContainer'>";
                        while($row = $arrayQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                $id = $row["attId"];
                                $img = $row["attThumbnail"];
                                $title = $row["attTitle"];
                                $tagline = $row["AttTagline"];
    
                        $results .= "<div class='nearbyAttractionListItem'>
                                        <a href='Attraction.php?attId=$id&title=$title' data-AttractionId='$id' 
                                        class'NearbyAttractionItem-url'>
                                        <img class='NearbyAttractionItem-thumbnail' src='$img' height='220' width=300'>
                                        <h3 class='NearbyAttractionItem-title'>$title</h3>
                                        <p class='NearbyAttractionItem-tagline'>$tagline</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>";
                        } // End of while loop
                    $results .= "</div>"; // End of nearbyAttractionsItemsContainer
                    } // End of foreach loop
                    
                } // End of IF statement
    
                else {
                    $results = "<h3>There are No Nearby Attractions</h3>";
                } // End of Else statement
    
            return $results;         
    
        } // End of public function createNearbyAttractionsList
    
    } // End pf class NearbyAttractionsProvider
```