# PHP PDO statements array with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problematic query where I can't protect it because PDO doesn't protect the array.
Example:
(1,2,3 are example ids).

```
Select store_id FROM store WHERE store_id IN (1,2,3)
```

My code looked something like

```
$params['storeId'] = $filter['storeId'];
$types['storeId'] = PDO::PARAM_INT;

$sql = 'Select store_id FROM store WHERE store_id IN (:storeId)'
```

I event put storeId in loop so I can loop more storeIds ( user input ) but It always queries only one storeId.

Is there a way so I can protect my query ( mySQL IN operator ) with PDO statement. ?

Comment: I figured this out with this comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48923246/15130815